# Error during compare date format in sqlite query

Tags: sqlite

I was writing an application on c#, which is save DateTime to the Text field in the database.
Format of date is:

> '1/15/2020 14:48:44', '2/11/2020 12:53:59' and etc

Now I want to get records with SQL query by the last few days. 
I understand that I need convert text to date, and compare. But SQL query return 0 results. My query is:

```
select * from LogRootProcessing where strftime(dateparsing) < strftime('%MM/%DD/%YYYY %HH:%MM:%SS','2/11/2020 12:53:59')
```

Could you please advise how to fix the query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a format sqlite date and time functions understand, so they return null. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Plus `strftime()` needs at least two arguments... Not sure what `strftime(dateparsing)` is supposed to do.